# SED AWK to strip data from log file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

Hi I have the following entries in log file. 
I need to produce  a list of names in the name field if I see Denied on the line above. So I need to get something like:

Sally
Matt

Linda

Can you help me with this and I would appreciate if you could explain the command so I can use it later on for other logs.

```
<!-- user 1 -- >
<ABC  12345 "123" text="*Denied: ths is aa test status="0" > 
   <key flags="tdst"  name="sally"  />
<userbody>
</Status>

<!-- user 2 -- >
<ABD  12345 "123" text="*Denied: ths is aa test status="0" > 
  <key flags="tdst"  name="Matt"  />
<userbody>
</Status>

<!-- user 3 -- >
<ABD  12345 "123" text="*Denied: ths is aa test status="0" > 
   <key flags="tdst"  name="Linda"  />
<userbody>
</Status>
```

Regards

Comment: This looks like broken XML to me, which may be just because you've changed it to provide us with a sample of your input. If it's valid XML in reality, you should use an XML tool to do this, rather than a text processing tool such as awk or sed.

Comment: Edit your sample input to include some blocks that you do NOT want the names printed from. Printing the text you want is always trivial, it's not printing the text you DON'T want that's hard. For the output don't say `I need to get something like` as that ambiguity is hard to program - just show EXACTLY what the output is you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GNU sed could work

```
sed -n -r '/Denied:/{N; s/^.*name="([^"]*)".*$/\1/; p}' file
```

n is skip printing lines
r using extended regular expressions, used for grouping here, to not escape () characters
N is reading next line and adding it to pattern
   space
s/input/output/ is substitution
^ is start of line, so   ^.*name=" will find everything till [^"] first next quote.
$ is end  of line
[^"] is any character which is not " (set negation)
\1 is taking only matching group i.e. ([^"]*)
p is printing line (when prev condition Denied is fullfiled on processed 2
   lines

output

```
sally
Matt
Linda
```

Comment: cool this works .. not sure how can u explain please how sed command works here?

Comment: Sure glad it worked, i've added some explanation. If anything more to explain mention me here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -rn '/Denied/{n;s#(.+)(name="(\w+))"(.+)#\3#p}' < sample.txt
```

`/Denied/` - search for the keyword
`{n;` - if found then read next line
`s#(.+)(name="(\w+))"(.+)#\3#p` - lookup regex groups and print out only the third one, which is equal to the name within quotes in your data sample.